# PWA List access via REST from sub site

Tags: workflow, rest, project-server

I've got a Project server site that needs to access to the values of a list stored in the PWA when a new row is added in a list of its own.

For that I've created a workflow using Sharepoint Designer.

When I invoke `...PWA/_api/web/Lists('GUID')` from that workflow I always get the same error: **Unauthorized**. Even making the call using "App Step".

But if I invoke that service directly from chrome it works fine.

Any idea which permission is needed or what is happening? I've been looking the permissions and found nothing unusual.

Comment: what account is the workflow running as? the app step will run as the author of the workflow.

Comment: Hi @Mike, the workflow starts when a new row is added, so if I am correct the workflow will run with the account of the row adder user. I've tried with a user that has full control over the site and over the list.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the error. I needed to give full control permissions to the user that was running the workflow. Which I found using ULSViewer.

Hope it helps anybody else.